# Develop IoT Edge modules for Windows devices Tutorial Build Error

Tags: c#, docker, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I have followed all the steps in the tutorial [Tutorial: Develop IoT Edge modules for Windows devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-windows?view=iotedge-2020-11)

I have signed into docker desktop.

However when I try and build and publish I get the following error in the output window

```
> DOCKER_HOST: 
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 
DOCKER_CERT_PATH: 
Additional Env Variables: 
------ Build and Push IoT Edge Modules started: Platform: Windows Amd64, Configuration: Release ------
The deployment manifest is generated at C:\Users\bar\source\repos\AzureIotEdgeApp3\config\deployment.windows-amd64.json
docker build --rm -f "C:\Users\bar\source\repos\IotEdgeModule3\Dockerfile.windows-amd64" -t FOO.azurecr.io/iotedgemodule3:0.0.1-windows-amd64  "C:\Users\bar\source\repos\IotEdgeModule3"
#2 (internal) load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.1s
#1 (internal) load build definition from Dockerfile.windows-amd64
#1 transferring dockerfile: 46B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.1s
#3 (internal) load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-n...
#3 DONE 0.0s
#4 (internal) load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanos...
#4 DONE 0.0s
#5 (stage-1 1/3) FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-...
#5 CACHED
#9 (internal) load build context
#9 transferring context: 1.20kB 0.0s done
#9 DONE 0.2s
#6 (stage-1 2/3) WORKDIR /app
#6 ERROR: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/78d2cb8633edf0eef3af53faff16f4b1570ca332555085bcadcb185c037611dd/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
#7 (build-env 1/6) FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-18...
#7 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809@sha256:aeab6d06ece872b88e59c4da0a98aa64e637aa979a161923658c5f7ef74b9699 done
#7 sha256:918abb37d3f2ac5ee5f9ad3d2017bebcdc353838e7097f5be7fda8c7df590489 4.36kB / 4.36kB done
#7 sha256:aeab6d06ece872b88e59c4da0a98aa64e637aa979a161923658c5f7ef74b9699 3.43kB / 3.43kB done
#7 CANCELED

 > (stage-1 2/3) WORKDIR /app:

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/78d2cb8633edf0eef3af53faff16f4b1570ca332555085bcadcb185c037611dd/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
(ERROR): Build docker image failed: #2 (internal) load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.1s
#1 (internal) load build definition from Dockerfile.windows-amd64
#1 transferring dockerfile: 46B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.1s
#3 (internal) load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-n...
#3 DONE 0.0s
#4 (internal) load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanos...
#4 DONE 0.0s
#5 (stage-1 1/3) FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-...
#5 CACHED
#9 (internal) load build context
#9 transferring context: 1.20kB 0.0s done
#9 DONE 0.2s
#6 (stage-1 2/3) WORKDIR /app
#6 ERROR: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/78d2cb8633edf0eef3af53faff16f4b1570ca332555085bcadcb185c037611dd/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
#7 (build-env 1/6) FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-18...
#7 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809@sha256:aeab6d06ece872b88e59c4da0a98aa64e637aa979a161923658c5f7ef74b9699 done
#7 sha256:918abb37d3f2ac5ee5f9ad3d2017bebcdc353838e7097f5be7fda8c7df590489 4.36kB / 4.36kB done
#7 sha256:aeab6d06ece872b88e59c4da0a98aa64e637aa979a161923658c5f7ef74b9699 3.43kB / 3.43kB done
#7 CANCELED

 > (stage-1 2/3) WORKDIR /app:

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/78d2cb8633edf0eef3af53faff16f4b1570ca332555085bcadcb185c037611dd/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
```

I am trying this on a Windows 10 Pro, x64 computer with latest version of Visual studio Version 16.8.0 and Docker Windows Desktop (stable) installed yesterday.

I have tried reinstalling docker and creating the visual studio projects, however I still get the same error.

this is docker file Dockerfile.windows-amd64:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1809
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IotEdgeModule3.dll"]
```

Comment: did you switch to Windows containers? I believe that the docker desktop by the default is using Linux containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kgalic is correct, I Docker was running using Linux by Default. I switched to Windows by using the context menu on the docker icon in the system try.